# IOS: UISearchBar partly covering UINavigationBar with prompt

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, prompt, swift4

I am using a UITableViewController with a UISearchBar. The UITableViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController. When the table view is shown the search bar is at the top as expected (below the navigation bar). The navigation bar is showing a title and a prompt.

When I click the search bar, it is moved up and hides the title in my navigation bar. The prompt is still visible.
When I do not use a prompt, the search bar is still below the navigation bar as expected after I clicked it.

I have created a very simple project to demonstrate my problem. The project has the following file for a UITableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class searchTVC: UITableViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    fileprivate let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Title"
        navigationItem.prompt = "prompt"

        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        // Add search bar
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        // remove separators for empty table
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

In the storyboard there is only an empty UITableViewController that is embedded in an UINavigationController. The result is shown below.

[image]
[image]

If you comment out the line that sets the prompt the behavior is as expected.

I recently updated my code to Swift 4. I cannot recall that I saw this behavior when using Swift 3, but I am not completely sure that it was introduced with Swift 4.

Am I missing something in the code or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set these in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .bottom
```